# Using the method outside of Context returns different result EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have the method, that is placed at DbContext class, which gets the table name from DB depends on type:

```
 public Type GetDataType(Type type)
        {
                if (!type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Test)))
                    throw new ArgumentException("The Wrong type provided. A subclass of Test is expected.");

                Type testType = GetEntityType(type);

                TestAttribute testAttribute = testType.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TestAttribute>().SingleOrDefault() as TestAttribute;

                if (testAttribute == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Test attribute not found");

                Type result = testAttribute.DataType;         

                return result;             
        }


    public Type GetEntityType(Type type)
    {
        return type.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies" ? type.BaseType : type;
    }
```

What I am trying to do is moving those methods to the BL, but the `testAttribute` becomes `null` after, despite the fact that `testType.GetCustomAttributes(false)` returns the same in two cases.

My test attribute is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class TestAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public Type DataType { get; private set; }

        public TestAttribute(Type dataType)
        {
            DataType = dataType;
        }
    }
```

And the class I am working with is:

```
 [Test(typeof(testDataItem))]
    public class classTest : Test
    {
     //some fields
    }
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: I can't see anything wrong.  Please put that code together into a short, complete repro of your issue.

Comment: I can't see how falling outside of the scope of the DbContext would affect attributes. What I would check is whether possibly the "TestAttribute" is being resolved to a different class in the new assembly? Frameworks such as NUnit/MSTest have TestAttributes defined,  if you go to definition on both the attribute definition on your entity, and then again from the code doing the OfType<> call, does it go to the same correct definition?

Comment: @StevePy, you are correct) thanks